# Clearing a Password text box in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have two boxes one with username [text] and one with password [password].

I'm using this code in the CodeBehind:

```
  protected void Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "";
        TextBox2.Text = "";
    }
```

[asp.net/html]

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="24px" Style="text-align: center" Width="209px" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
```

The first text box clears but the second doesn't. Is there a special way to do this in ASP.NET?

Comment: Do you show us your HTML code?

Comment: odd. I set up a quick project to mimic your description and for me, it's the first textbox that isn't clearing

Comment: well you can ignore my comment. It's been so long since I last used web forms! I forgot to bind the OnClick event. Did you do the same? Can I see your button html?

Comment: If the button click is executing, then it is highly likely that the browser is putting that password in.  Likely you clicked "yes" to save my password which most of them ask about.  Clear those browser settings and you should be good.

Answer (score 3):

Hi I don't know what happend in your HTML but I wrote this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="24px" Style="text-align: center" Width="209px" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

And the codebehind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = "";
            TextBox2.Text = "";
        }
```

And It works, the only thing is when the button does not have the onclick only It will clean the password texbox, check it and maybe this is your problem.

Comment: without that OnClick attribute, it won't execute your click event handler. The clearing of the password textbox is a browser behavior.

Comment: @norepro, it depends-- if you have AutoEventWireUp=True in the page, you shouldn't need the onclick attribute.  It'll find the method by convention.

Comment: @ps2goat The `AutoEventWireup="true"` is for default in true when you create a web page, you can test and see with this event and without onclick method the textbox never is cleaned.

Answer (score 2):

When the `TextMode` property of the `<asp:TextBox />` is set to `Password` the value set in the `Text` property will not display at runtime, Or you can say it won't have any effect to set the `Text` property. This is by design to prevent the unmasked password from being displayed in the HTML source of the page.

As a solution, use this::

```
this.TextBox2.Attributes["value"] = "";
```

OR::

```
this.TextBox2.Attributes.Add("value", "");
```

[Check here](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/12/18/1300.aspx) for full details.

Answer (score 0):

```
textbox1.text = string.empty;
textbox2.text = string.empty;
```